# empty rule in ocamlyacc

Tags: ocaml, yacc

I have the following lexer rules:

```
let ws = [' ' '\t' '\n']+
... 
| ws                  {Printf.printf "%s" (Lexing.lexeme lexbuf); WS(Lexing.lexeme lexbuf)}
```

And the following parser rules:

```
%token <string>  WORD WS 
cs               :  LSQRB wsornon choices wsornon RSQRB {$2}
                 ;

wsornon          : /* nothing */
                 | WS {$1}
                 ;

choices          :  choice {$1}
                 |  choices choice {$2}
                 ;

choice           :  CHOICE LCURLYB mainbody RCURLYB {$3}
                 ;
```

I basically want to get `wsornon` to match with whitespace or nothing. But `cs` gives syntax errors for the case without whitespace (which corresponds to the empty rule).

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even if you parse the empty stream, you should have a production rule:

```
wsornon:
  |    { something for nothing }
  | WS { something for whitespace }
```

Note that [menhir](http://gallium.inria.fr/~fpottier/menhir/) has an `OPTION` parametrized rule that is just fine for this kind of things, so that you don't have to write another rule for that. In fact `OPTION(foo)` return a production of type `bar option` if rule `foo` returns something of type `bar`, while you're going to ignore them anyway, so that's a bit of a different situation.

If you want to ignore whitespace, why don't you drop it altogether at the lexer step? Is it useful somewhere else in your grammar? I'd rather hack the lexer a bit to have some whitespace token just after some tokens where I know they're important than have them pollute my whole grammar. Of course, menhir allows to define parametrized rules that could help with that (example below untested):

```
ws(rule):
| LIST(WS) result = rule LIST(WS) { result }
```